# what are the techniques to extract files safely?

Tags: linux, security, virtualization

Yesterday I was making some experiments on [Slitaz](http://slitaz.org). It uses multiple initrd.img's to store files/changes.

I wanted to extract one of its initrd.gz images (which is a cpio archive) to a folder, edit/remove them, repack again.

I used this code:

```
cat rootfs.img | cpio -idvm
```

Then all files are extracted to my root filesystem. My whole OS is corrupted. (What an emberrasing situation...)

What should I do to make such operations safely but in an easy way? Chroot? LXC? (VirtualBox is the last resort)

Comment: there is a unix.stackexchange.com but this site might be ok

Comment: This question has been crossposted to [Unix.se] http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137160/what-are-the-techniques-to-extract-files-safely

Answer (score 1):

The option you want is `--no-absolute-filenames`:

> Create all files relative to the current directory in copy-in mode, even if they have an absolute file name in the archive.